# How to parse xml file with perl based on attribute using grep

Tags: xml, perl, grep, xml-twig

I'm new to **perl** and have been struggling. I have an xml file with the following structure, but with thousands of entries:

**test.xml**

```
<msms_pipeline_analysis>
    <spectrum_query spectrum="H_TPP08.04885.04885.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="48887">
        <search_result>
          <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
          </search_hit>
        </search_result>
    </spectrum_query>
    <spectrum_query spectrum="L_TPP08.05765.04785.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="48856">
        <search_result>
          <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
          </search_hit>
        </search_result>        
    </spectrum_query>
    <spectrum_query spectrum="L_TPP10.87945.3485.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="4885">
        <search_result>
          <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
          </search_hit>
        </search_result>        
    </spectrum_query>
</msms_pipeline_analysis>
```

I need to parse/delete the **"spectrum_query"** nodes that do **not** contain in the attribute **"spectrum"** the string in this example "TPP08" i.e. in reality what it is between the first underscore and the first dot (as later I would like to subset TPP09, TPP10, etc), eg.

H_**TPP08**.04885.04885.2

and retain the file with its structure.

By searching I have come up with many solutions that look at deleting nodes fulfilling an attribute. In my case, such solution can **delete** a node in question:

```
#!/urs/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ('pretty_print' => 'indented' ) -> parsefile ( 'test.xml' ); 
foreach my $element ( $twig -> get_xpath('spectrum_query[@spectrum="H_TPP08.04885.04885.2"]') ) {
   $element -> delete;
}

$twig -> print; 

open XML, ">output.xml";
print XML $twig->toString();
close XML;
```

which deletes the first node. But only the specific one, and the real file has thousands of entries. Moreover, I want to **keep** the ones that fulfill the criteria, as the other way around I would have to run the script for every other entry that does not contain spectrum TPP08 (eg TPP09, TPP10, etc).

As to determine the string, so far I have come with this

```
$string = qw(H_TPP08.05164.05164.2);
my ($substring2) = $string =~ m:.*_(.+?)?\.:;
print "$substring2\n";
```

Which outputs **TPP08** what I want, as I would need to keep the nodes with H_TPP08.XXXX or L_TPP08.XXXX

So far I have not found if there's a way to do a negative subset like in R with "!" of the grep, and include the grep in the matching of the string on the attribute so this can be parsed. For what I have read most likely I would need to make an array with the string of the attribute of all entries

`my @array = map { $tag -> att('spectrum') } $twig -> get_xpath('//spectrum_query');`

and then evaluate sequentially each entry after grep and compare it to the matching string, and then only keep the nodes fulfilling that. But I cannot wrap my head around a solution for that with my basic perl knowledge.

Any help will be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most "twiggish" way to do this would be to go through the file and discard the elements you don't want while outputting the rest .

- use `twig_roots` to match the proper `spectrum_query` elements, and do nothing with them, effectively discarding them,
- let the rest of the XML be output as is, using `twig_print_outside_roots`

This will be very memory efficient, since pretty much nothing will be kept in memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw(open);

use XML::Twig;

my $target = 'TPP08';
my $input  = 'test.xml';
my $output = 'output.xml';
open( my $out, '>:utf8', $output);

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots          => { qq{spectrum_query[\@spectrum=~/^[^_]*_$target\./]} => 1, },
                twig_print_outside_roots => $out,
              )
         ->parsefile( $input);
```

note that each discarded element will produce an empty line in the output, white space management is tricky. If it matters you can get rid of those with  `grep -v` or by using `xml_pp`.

Comment: This is my favorite partial solution. The ones from @matt and @wolfrevokcats work on my test example. However on big xml files they don't work. It might be because there are nodes withouth   ending above <spectrum_query>. The approach using twig_roots is the one I would like to keep as leaves the rest untouched. It works well in big files but it **deletes** the nodes containing the $target. So, I have to run it sequentially to delete each entries that are not needed. Is there a way to make the negative regex with `!` so to keep the file untouched but without the nodes containing the `$target`?

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = <<'EOF';
<msms_pipeline_analysis>
  <spectrum_query spectrum="H_TPP08.04885.04885.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="48887">
    <search_result>
      <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
      </search_hit>
    </search_result>
  </spectrum_query>
  <spectrum_query spectrum="L_TPP08.05765.04785.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="48856">
    <search_result>
      <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
      </search_hit>
    </search_result>
  </spectrum_query>
  <spectrum_query spectrum="L_TPP10.87945.3485.2" start_scan="4885" end_scan="4885">
    <search_result>
      <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1">
      </search_hit>
    </search_result>
  </spectrum_query>
</msms_pipeline_analysis>
EOF

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented')->parse($xml);

for my $element ($twig->get_xpath('/msms_pipeline_analysis/spectrum_query')) {
    next if $element->att('spectrum') =~ /TPP08/;
    $element->delete;
}

$twig->print;
```

Output:

```
<msms_pipeline_analysis>
  <spectrum_query end_scan="48887" spectrum="H_TPP08.04885.04885.2" start_scan="4885">
    <search_result>
      <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1"></search_hit>
    </search_result>
  </spectrum_query>
  <spectrum_query end_scan="48856" spectrum="L_TPP08.05765.04785.2" start_scan="4885">
    <search_result>
      <search_hit calc_neutral_pep_mass="2348.060995306391" hit_rank="1"></search_hit>
    </search_result>
  </spectrum_query>
</msms_pipeline_analysis>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_xpath` with a regexp expression on an attribute

```
foreach my $element ( $twig -> get_xpath('spectrum_query[@spectrum =~ /^(?!\w_TPP08\.)/]') ) {
   $element -> delete;
}
```

Or you can check every node for attribute match:

```
foreach my $element ( $twig -> get_xpath('spectrum_query[@spectrum]') ) {
  if ($element->att('spectrum')!~ m/^\w_TPP08\./) {
    $element -> delete;
  }
}
```